# after log in to superset, redirect failed

Tags: redirect, apache-superset

while login to
http://58.177.151.102:8088/login/
it will redirect me to
http://58.177.151.102:8088/login/?next=http://58.177.151.102:8088/superset/welcome/
And this only happens to me when i use the internet in my company. And don't know how to fix it.

It works well when using other network. I want to know how to fix it.

I hope to redirect successfully.

**PS: error in docker logs**

```
123.1.253.113 - - [26/Jun/2023:07:35:03 +0000] "GET /login/?next=http://58.177.151.102:8088/superset/welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 200 51415 "http://58.177.151.102:8088/superset/welcome/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/114.0.1823.58"
2023-06-26 07:35:22,166:INFO:flask_wtf.csrf:The CSRF session token is missing.
Refresh CSRF token error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 261, in protect
    validate_csrf(self._get_csrf_token())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 103, in validate_csrf
    raise ValidationError("The CSRF session token is missing.")
wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing.

 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2313, in preprocess_request
    rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 229, in csrf_protect
    self.protect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 264, in protect
    self._error_response(e.args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 307, in _error_response
    raise CSRFError(reason)
flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
2023-06-26 07:35:22,166:WARNING:superset.views.base:Refresh CSRF token error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 261, in protect
    validate_csrf(self._get_csrf_token())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 103, in validate_csrf
    raise ValidationError("The CSRF session token is missing.")
wtforms.validators.ValidationError: The CSRF session token is missing.

 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.preprocess_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2313, in preprocess_request
    rv = self.ensure_sync(before_func)()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 229, in csrf_protect
    self.protect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 264, in protect
    self._error_response(e.args[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_wtf/csrf.py", line 307, in _error_response
    raise CSRFError(reason)
flask_wtf.csrf.CSRFError: 400 Bad Request: The CSRF session token is missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Superset are you using?  One possibility if you're using the latest version from Github (it will say version 0.0.0-dev in the Superset UI) is that this could be caused by a [change recently merged in](https://github.com/apache/superset/pull/24256) that sets `SESSION_PROTECTION = "strong"`.  This was causing a redirection loop for me like what you describe and could vary with the different networks.

Try setting `SESSION_PROTECTION = "basic"` in your Superset config and see if that fixes it.  This argument was not present in Superset configurations prior to version 2.1.1.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work to me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it went away after switching from Safari to the MS Edge browser.

Comment: it helps me sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by fix the version, not always the newest.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).